Force a single sonnected set for segmentation model using U-Net
I have a simple U-Net model for 2 classes, binary, image segmentation.
The classes are background and an single object.
The object is a connected set.
Namely the mask is a single blob of pixels with no holes in it.
Effectively, it is a single connected component.
Is there a way to force or promote such result using the loss function?
I currently use Tversky loss.
It is considered a type of region based loss.
Yet I still get results of several blobs and even some single pixels here and there.
It seems that YOLO models for segmentation can force such case.
How can it be done?
